# Makefile issue comparing strings

Tags: string, makefile, comparison

In my makefile I need to check if a file starts with a bash shebang.

I get that value by doing this

```
PROJECT_AUTOINSTALL_FIRST_LINE := $$(head -n 1 ./autoinstall_script.sh)
```

And then I compare it with this value:

```
BASH_SHEBANG = \#!/bin/bash
```

Then I check if they're equal by doing

```
ifneq ($(PROJECT_AUTOINSTALL_FIRST_LINE),$(BASH_SHEBANG))
    @${ERROR_ECHO} "The FIRST line in project autoinstall file MUST be $(BASH_SHEBANG)."
endif
```

The issue is that condition is always true no matter if file starts with shebang or not.
I made a debug echo in order to test equality in a visual way and got this:

[image]

They seem to be equal at first sight but code is not telling so. Do you know what am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What

```
PROJECT_AUTOINSTALL_FIRST_LINE := $$(head -n 1 ./autoinstall_script.sh)
```

does is just assign the literal string `$(head -n 1 ./autoinstall_script.sh)` to make variable `PROJECT_AUTOINSTALL_FIRST_LINE`. Not what you want. Try the following, instead:

```
PROJECT_AUTOINSTALL_FIRST_LINE := $(shell head -n 1 ./autoinstall_script.sh)
```

Comment: Works like a charm...but can't understand the issue yet. Why then in the output they looked to be equal? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Because when the shell executed `echo $(head...)`, it first executed the `head...` and echoed the result. See the _Command substitution_ section of the manual of your shell.

Comment: If you want to see the value of a make variable, do not use a recipe. Prefer the `info` make function and put it flat in your Makefile: `$(info MYVAR = |$(MYVAR)|)` (the `|` are optional, it is just a way to show leading or trailing spaces).